# Time Limited Function

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

Let's say I have the following:

function `requestValue`: I need to call this function several times. Each time I call it, it should calculate some value `X` then call another function `submitValue(X)` with the calculated value as a parameter. However, if it doesn't finish the calculation within let's say 5 seconds, it should call `submitValue(-1)`.

Note that this is just an example of what I need in order to make the question as simple as possible, the the functions do not calculate anything (sleep is used to simulate exceeding the time limit).

What I did is extend the Thread class, and added a function to mark the thread as stopped:

```
class myThread extends Thread{
    boolean stop = false;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200*rand.nextInt(10));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (stop == false)
            submitValue(1);
    }
    void Stop(){
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the `requestValue` function:

```
void requestValue(){
    myThread thread = new myThread();

    Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000 , new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                thread.Stop();
                submitValue(-1);
            }
        }    
    );
    myTimer.setRepeats(false);
    myTimer.start();
    thread.start();
}
```

The `submitValue` function currently just prints out the parameter (1 or -1).

This will prevent the function `submitValue(1)` from being called when the time limit is exceeded, however `submitValue(-1)` is always called. How can I let the listener know that `submitValue(1)` has been called or not so I don't call it again? And is there a better way to do this than the way I'm using?

Another problem is that all `1`s are being printed before all `-1`s, why is that happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things. First, don't extend Thread. Implement a Runnable, which you can do anonymously if you like, and pass that to the Thread constructor.

Second, don't create a second Timer thread. That's overly complicated and probably at the root of your problem. Let the main thread block, instead.

Use Thread.join(long millis) to do the timeout. If the thread is still active, set the "stop" flag. (Note that it should be private volatile, with a method to make it true. The volatile keyword will ensure that the worker thread will see the value when it changes.) then return -1. Otherwise, return the calculated value.